# Use of GetMessage() function

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, visual-c++, user-interface

I have gone through msdn to know `GetMessage` and `DispatchMessage(&msg);` function. 
I had created a button application using visual c++ (x64).

The problem was when I used `GetMessage` my program was going in infinite loop. Suddenly I commented the `GetMessage` part and my buttons working fine (I just have two buttons that just two show different dialog box on different button click events).

I have two questions:

1. First, any ideas why on removing the `GetMessage` solved my problem (for your knowledge I have used `CreateDialogParam` and `DialogProc` for my button controls).
2. Second, as I understand (please correct me if I am wrong), `GetMessage` receives the message (if there are so many messages at once) and after that `DispatchMessage(&msg);` dispatches those messages one by one to let them finish their work. If the first finished then the second message is dispatched and so on, until all the messages have been processed.

My code is below:

```
m_hwndPreview = CreateDialogParam( g_hInst,MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_MAINDIALOG), m_hwndParent,(DLGPROC)DialogProc, (LPARAM)this);
if (m_hwndPreview == NULL)
{
    hr = HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(GetLastError());
}
BOOL bRet;
MSG  msg;
while ( (bRet=GetMessage (& msg, 0, 0, 0)) != 0)
{
    if (bRet == -1)
    {
        bRet = HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(GetLastError());
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Hurr  i am the error",L"Error", MB_ICONERROR | MB_OK);
    }

    else if (!IsDialogMessage (m_hwndPreview, & msg))
    {
        TranslateMessage ( & msg );
        DispatchMessage ( & msg );
        MessageBox(NULL, L"there is no error in receivung the message", L"Error", MB_ICONERROR | MB_OK);
    }
} 
int refMsg= (int)msg.wParam;
refMsg;
```

Comment: Please, show relevant code.

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_loop_in_Microsoft_Windows

Comment: And double check that you're NOT passing a window handle to `GetMessage()` in your main message loop. Common mistake. Likewise, lookup [`IsDialogMessage()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645498(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: You make it sound like `GetMessage` retrieves all messages at once and then `DispatchMessage` dispatches them one after another. This is incorrect. Both `GetMessage` and `DispatchMessage` handle a single message at a time.

Comment: @ all... the code is as above.

Comment: @Tim there is one more question. I am developing a button application on which i have two buttons "Next" and "Previous" button which create the preview of "Image" and"HTML" file respectively. when i don't use GetMessage those buttons works fine(otherwise infinite loop)for the first time click on both buttons but when i resize the window(on which i am rendering the preview of these two) then it show some overlapping of html preview over image(but for the first click on both buttons it works fine). Do you think that this overlapping may be due to absence of Getmessage & dispatch message code ???

Comment: @tim an there is no overlapping on resizing the window for the first time(it works fine) . overlapping occurs when i resize window after the first click.( and when i click button again it removes the overlapping for some time but on resizing it again starts..and again onclicking the button it removes overlapping and again on resizing it overlapps)